# akka - Java stateful actor persistence

Tags: akka

I am developing an application using `AKKA` (Java API).
I have a few questions:

1. In an actor class, is it okay to have a few data structures (Example: HashMap) as part of the actor state (attributes of the class)?
2. If the actor dies, actor will be restarted by the SUpervisory actor. However, I am wondering how to restore the contents of these data structures. 
   Please suggest?

Initially, I thought of using `Cassandra` to persist the data as and when this actor receives messages to save the member objects to `Cassandra`. Not sure if this is the right approach.
Please help

Thank you,
KS

Answer (score 2):

Have a child actor that performs any and all risky operations, and have your actor's supervisor strategy set up to fit your needs for that child.

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is keep it in data related to actors in Redis similar to how you can create a durable mailbox. In what situation is your actor dying?